# mongoimport results in bad ObjectId format

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport, mongoexport, mongo-express

I exported a local database using the mongo-express export functionality. To my knowledge mongo-express uses mongoexport to generate the documents as JSON files.
Here is an example of an exported collection called 'roles':

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"60f6d845caa1861dcf1631ae"},"name":"Admin"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"60f6d845caa1861dcf1631af"},"name":"User"}
```

Now I create a collection 'roles' on another mongodb instance and import the monogexport JSON seen above.
This is the result of the import, taken the "Admin" record as an example:

```
{
    _id: '60f6d845caa1861dcf1631ae',
    name: 'Admin'
}
```

When I query the database through my backend using ObjectIds this obviously does not work, since the datatype has become a string now. This is how the original record looks like (and is what I expect to see after the import):

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('60f6d845caa1861dcf1631ae'),
    name: 'Admin'
}
```

My question is quite simple: What the heck is going on?
I am using mongodb v5.0.0 and mongo-express v1.0.0-alpha.4.

I hate web development.

EDIT:

Just tested it with mongo-express v0.54.0. Same result.